# R write.csv not handling characters like é correctly

Tags: r, csv, utf-8, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

When I look at data in R, it has characters like "é" displayed correctly.

I export it to excel using write.csv.  When I open the csv file, "é" is displayed as "√©".  Is the problem with write.csv or with excel?  What can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps try to use the `encoding="UTF-8"` argument

Answer (score 6):

Try the `write_excel_csv()` function from the `readr` package

```
readr::write_excel_csv(your_dataframe, "file_path")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with Excel. Try Importing data instead of Opening the file.

Go to: 'Data' --> 'From Text/CSV' and then select '65001:Unicode (UTF-8)'. That will match the encoding from R.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try experimenting with the parameter fileEncoding of write.csv:

```
write.csv(..., fileEncoding="UTF-16LE")
```

From write.csv documentation:

> fileEncoding *character string*: if non-empty declares the encoding to
> be used on a file (not a connection) so the character data can be
> re-encoded as they are written. See file.
>
> CSV files do not record an encoding, and this causes problems if they
> are not ASCII for many other applications. Windows Excel 2007/10 will
> open files (e.g., by the file association mechanism) correctly if they
> are ASCII or UTF-16 (use fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE") or perhaps in the
> current Windows codepage (e.g., "CP1252"), but the ‘Text Import
> Wizard’ (from the ‘Data’ tab) allows far more choice of encodings.
> Excel:mac 2004/8 can import only ‘Macintosh’ (which seems to mean Mac
> Roman), ‘Windows’ (perhaps Latin-1) and ‘PC-8’ files. OpenOffice 3.x
> asks for the character set when opening the file.